# Fody Costura Does Not Embed SkiaSharp DLL

Tags: c#, dll, skiasharp, skia, fody-costura

I created a solution that uses the Costura.Fody nuget package to merge referenced assemblies as embedded resources. I want this so that I can create a single exe for my application. This was working great for a while until I added a reference to SkiaSharp (specifically the nuget packages SkiaSharp and SkiaSharp.Svg). The libSkiaSharp.dll is not embedded and instead built in the startup project folder, and I can't run the program exe on its own unless I keep the dll in the same folder. Is there a way to fix this?

Here's the steps to reproduce this:
1. Create a new WPF project
2. Add the Costura.Fody and Fody nuget packages.
3. Add a file called FodyWeavers.xml with the contents set to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Weavers>
  <Costura/>
</Weavers>
```

4. Build and run the exe file in the bin/Debug folder. Notice that program will start up even if you move the exe to a new location.
5. Add SkiaSharp and SkiaSharp.Svg nuget packages.
6. get an svg file and add it to your project directory
7. add the following code to your MainWindow constructor:

   var svg = new SKSvg();
   svg.Load("image.svg");
   SKCanvas canvas = new SKCanvas(new SKBitmap());
   canvas.DrawPicture(svg.Picture);
8. notice that if you copy the image file and the exe and place in another directory, the exe will not start up. This occurs because it can't find libSkiaSharp.dll.

Comment: By the way I think the reason for this issue has do to with the fact that the libSkiaSharp.dll is a native library. However I've a tried adding a reference to the libary in the FodyWeavers.xml file, using the IncludeAssemblies tag. But so far I haven't figured out how to get it to embed all dlls.

Answer (score 3):

Create a Costura32 and/or Costura64 folder in your project. Copy libSkiaSharp.dll into the appropriate directory depending on its bitness. Costura will automatically unpack and load native binaries from those directories.

Comment: This was helpful because it does in fact work. However, if I were to update the SkiaSharp nuget package then those files could be out of date without someone knowing. Adding a post build event to copy the libSkiaSharp files from the debug folder to the Costura folders won't work because the files need to be referenced as embedded resources. A successful build depends on the files being there so they can't be copied post build. I also can't copy from the nuget package folder because there are different libSKiaSharp file for different versions of Windows.

Comment: What about setting up a pre-build event?

Comment: I can't do a pre-build event either because the files have not been copied to the the debug folder at that point. They are copied after the project is built. It's frustrating because I know I can make it work, but it's not ideal.

Comment: Can you do two builds, start with a prebuild and embeding them on the second build?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Weavers>
  <Costura>
    <IncludeAssemblies>
        libSkiaSharp
    </IncludeAssemblies>
  </Costura>
</Weavers>
```

Comment: Build fails when I add this, with the following error: "Fody/Costura: Assembly 'libSkiaSharp' cannot be found (not even as CopyLocal='false'), please update the configuration"